# Why can't I create a user defined username and password in Azure for git?

Tags: node.js, azure, credentials

I've been trying for a while to create a username and password inside the FTPS credentials window of my app deployment center, but every time I introduce something in these slots I can't save my changes, and I need it to push my webpage from my local repository, because it asks for this credentials

[image: without the username]

[image: trying to enter the username i want]

I've tried to create the user defined username and password in other projects but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Azure App Service with runtime stack `NODE`.

I am able to create and use the `User Scope` credentials.

In your `Azure App Service` => `Deployment Center` => `Local Git/FTPS credentials`.

Under `User scope` add the Username, Password and click on Save.

[image]

[image]

- Only username is visible.
  [image]
- I have tried to connect by using this credential from local git.
  [image]

In the `local terminal/ command prompt` run the below commands to push the local code.

```cs
git add .
git commit -m "First Commit"
git remote add azure https://YourSiteName.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/YourSiteName.git
git push azure master
```

Git Credential Manager will be prompted.

[image]

Provided the credentials which I have created in Azure App Service, able to login successfully.

[image]